# Multiple Webbrowser controls running with different proxies

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to run a specific test on my server using a program that can run multiple requests (using Webbrowser control) at the same time but with different proxy settings.
What I am using now is working but only for one webbrowser control, im seeking advice for how to run multiple side-by-side.

```
 <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Public dwAccessType As Integer
    Public proxy As IntPtr
    Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure

Private Sub RefreshIESettings(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

    Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

    ' Filling in structure
    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

    ' Allocating memory
    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

    ' Converting structure to IntPtr
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

    Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
End Sub

Private Function loadpage()
    sInputLine = srFileReader.ReadLine()
    Debug.WriteLine("Starting Proxy " & sInputLine)
    RefreshIESettings(sInputLine)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = My.Settings.timeout * 1000
    'set label
    Label3.Text = "Attempting: " & sInputLine
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label3.Visible = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.MYSERVER.com")
    Return True
End Function
```

The loadpage() is being looped from a timer within DocumentCompleted Event.

Please help, I have searched -days- for a solution.

Comment: Passing IntPtr.Zero to InternetSetOption() is supported, it changes the machine wide setting.  You would have to obtain the HINTERNET handle that Internet Explorer uses to change that option for each session.  That is not possible, it doesn't expose it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with the webbrowser control itself, but you could manually retrieve the remote content using HttpWebRequest which has a Proxy property.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx